# Compare, extract and remove from a string array PHP

Tags: php, random, while-loop

I am an PHP noob that has been working for quite a while with the smallest of tasks.
Im trying to create a while loop that is alive until it finds a match, the strings that should match is two random strings from two arrays. But my problem is that the while loop gets stuck when they don't match sense the random values doesn't change after extraction. I just can't get my head around it, could someone please help me. This is the poor code that I've got.

```
$seed1 = array("kim","Jake","Mac","Pi");
$seed2 = array("Vi","Nik","Nis","Fid");

$teamTemp1 = $seed1[array_rand($seed1)];
$teamTemp2 = $seed2[array_rand($seed2)];

while(true){
    if($teamTemp1 == "Kim" && $teamTemp2 != "Nis"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Jake" && $teamTemp2 != "Fid"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Mac" && $teamTemp2 != "Vi"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Pi" && $teamTemp2 != "Fid"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never changing the values of `$teamTemp1` and `$teamTemp2`, so the loop will never end. You need to make those assignments inside the loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're working to do is randomizing a match-up between one member of each team ... but preventing specific match-ups you don't want to happen?

At any rate:  the basic concept of a while loop is to watch a changing base value until it reaches a valid state.

Problem 1:  Your base values don't change.  `$teamTemp1` and `$teamTemp2` never change inside the while loop.  So they keep looping over the same values over and over again.

Solution 1:  Move the randomizers inside the while loop, so that every iteration through gets you a new random match-up.

Problem 2:  The system could very easily get stuck if you're not careful about inputs and forbidden match-ups.

Solution 2:  I'd recommend adding an emergency-escape release if you don't find a valid match-up after so many tries.  This wouldn't find you a valid target, but it will at least keep you from locking up.

As so:

```
$seed1 = array("kim","Jake","Mac","Pi");
$seed2 = array("Vi","Nik","Nis","Fid");

$tries = 0;
while(true){
    $teamTemp1 = $seed1[array_rand($seed1)];  //  I change every time the loop repeats!
    $teamTemp2 = $seed2[array_rand($seed2)];  //  I change every time the loop repeats!

    if($teamTemp1 == "Kim" && $teamTemp2 != "Nis"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Jake" && $teamTemp2 != "Fid"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Mac" && $teamTemp2 != "Vi"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Pi" && $teamTemp2 != "Fid"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }

    if( $tries > 1000 ){
        return false;  //  Emergency Escape!
    }
    $tries++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you get me :) this is exact what I am gooing for

Comment: What would I need to do to remove a name from teamTemp1 after a succesful match @Wolfmanjoe ?

Comment: You mean, from $seed1 ?  Well, that depends - are you trying to make the teams smaller, or are you trying to increase the number of invalid match-ups?  Are you trying to make sure everyone on team 1 is matched up against a random individual from team 2?

Comment: If it matches on "Kim", I would like "Kim" to be removed from $seed1. But at the same time remove the chosen value from $seed2. Those to persons are not in the draw any more. After the 1 successful match there will be only 3 values left in seed1 and 3 in seed2. Should I create a new array maybe?

Comment: So you want to make sure you get a complete set of matchups?  I'm seeing potential problems if the random draw leaves nothing left but your 'prohibited' matchups.  Like, if Kim gets matched up with Vi, then Mac gets matched up with Nis... you are left with an unreachable dilemma for the last two.  Why are those four match-ups prohibited?  This will affect how to take this process to match up the whole team.

Comment: I did not see that as a problem until now, you'r right. They are prohibited because they have already been on the same team. How could I go around this problem? More If statements perhaps :) yes there should be a complete set of matchups. If I have a function that checks if all goes well otherwise re-scramble it :)?

Comment: Is the prohibited match-ups going to change every time the program is run?  Or is it the same every time?

Comment: They are not going to change, the "draw" will have the same restraints every time.

Comment: Well, then, instead of trying to make it generic, you might do something a little more exact.  Fid is the biggest challenge to match against, as he's only got two valid targets.  Pull a random match-up for him, first.  Then Vi, then Nis, and let the accommodating Nik take who's left.

Comment: Yes that would be the best way, a 50/50 draw for fid, then take care of the rest. When I found a match, should I remove from existing array or create a new array as a successful team. I really appreciate your help, It's always good to have some one to exchange thoughts with.

Comment: I support never destroying your original data.  Make a copy, then slowly consume the copy.

Answer (score 0):

In deed, you should do like this:

```
do { 
    $teamTemp1 = $seed1[array_rand($seed1)];
    $teamTemp2 = $seed2[array_rand($seed2)];

    if($teamTemp1 == "Kim" && $teamTemp2 != "Nis"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Jake" && $teamTemp2 != "Fid"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Mac" && $teamTemp2 != "Vi"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
    if($teamTemp1 == "Pi" && $teamTemp2 != "Fid"){
        echo $teamTemp1 ." + ".$teamTemp2;
        return false;
    }
} while(1);
```

Comment: [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)  -  array_rand pulls a key, not a value.